# Because qrreaderapp depends on sqflite >=1.1.7-dev.1 which requires SDK version >=2.5.0 <3.0.0, version solving failed. pub get failed (1)

Tags: android, flutter

tengo este error en mi aplicacion como puedo corregirlo? me aparecio despues de intentar instalar 2 paquetes, el de sqflite, y el path provider:

esto es lo que tengo en mi pubspec.yaml:

```
version: 1.0.0+1

environment:
  sdk: ">=2.1.0 <3.0.0"

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter

  # The following adds the Cupertino Icons font to your application.
  # Use with the CupertinoIcons class for iOS style icons.
  cupertino_icons: ^0.1.2
  qrcode_reader: ^0.4.4
  sqflite: ^1.3.0
  path_provider: ^1.6.5

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problema resulto, primero hay que instalar el powershell 5.1 o superior, segun tengo entendido en windows 10 ya suele venir instalado en mi caso estoy en windows 7, despues reiniciar el equipo para que funcione el powershell instalado, despues puede que aparececa que se no es compatible el androidX en la terminal al intentar hacer una ejecucion del codigo, si ese es el caso hay que entrar en la carpeta android del proyecto y en el archivo gradle.propierities hay que abrirlo y agregar esta linea de codigo y guardar los cambios:

```
android.useAndroidX=true

android.enableJetifier=true
```

el archivo quedaria asi:

```
org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx1536M

android.enableR8=true

android.useAndroidX=true

android.enableJetifier=true
```

en mi caso esto fue lo que tuve que hacer para que funcionara.

Answer (score 0):

Al parecer tu dependencia `sqflite` requiere una versiòn mayor de `flutter`, actualmente tienes:

```
sdk: ">=2.1.0 <3.0.0"
```

deberìa ser como minimo:

```
sdk: ">=2.5.0 <3.0.0"
```

[Actualiza tu versiòn de flutter](https://flutter-es.io/docs/development/tools/sdk/upgrading), usa el canal "estable" (`stable`):

```
flutter channel stable
flutter upgrade
```

Comment: me aparece este error, en foto lo subo

Answer (score 0):

este es el error que me aparece al final de la ejecucion del comando flutter upgrade --force

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Utiliza el enlace editar en tu pregunta para añadir información adicional. El botón Publicar respuesta se debe usar solamente para respuestas completas a la pregunta. - [Desde revisión](/review/low-quality-posts/207919)

Comment: Entendido para la proxima